# Footer issue with Twitter Bootstrap - is z-index the solution?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My template is based on [this](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/). To keep the footer 'sticky', the following CSS rules are used:

```
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    /* Margin bottom by footer height */
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;

    /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

/* Custom page CSS -------------------------------------------------- */
/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

body > .container {
    padding: 60px 15px 0;
}
.container .text-muted {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.footer > .container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

code {
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

However, when I include a table the pagination overlaps the footer. I think this is due to the way the DOM rules work.

There is a fix using `z-index`:

```
.footer {
    z-index: 4;
}
```

Is that the best approach?

If you take a look [here](http://concise-consultancy.com/g/) + change the 'Show entries to 100' you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `z-index` on the `footer` is the solution.

```
.footer {
    z-index: 2;
}
```